# How do I change the MIME type for a file?

Tags: mime-type

I have a file that is formatted as a `.doc`, but Nautilus and LibreOffice insists that it is a .txt. Both precise and Ubuntu 12.10 are that way, but Google Docs can convert it (after playing with it).

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: It opens, it just reads it as a `text/plain` document, not as a MS word doc. Removed the +'s, no difference.

Comment: could you try my edit @jrg . Damn, I need to know the answer :X :X

Comment: @Rinzwind I'm stupid, it's this thing. http://listarchives.libreoffice.org/global/users/msg22140.html

Answer (score 9):

To check if 'extension' mime type exist:

```
grep 'extension' /etc/mime.types
```

To create new mime type:

1. Open **/etc/mime.types** with text-editor(with root privileges)

   `gksudo gedit /etc/mime.types`
2. Add extension to **/etc/mime.types** in following format:

   `text/extension                   extension`

[For more info click here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AddingMimeTypes)

Comment: I did but nautilus doesn't recognize the change

Answer (score 1):

Could be something as simple as a mangled/intentionally changed header.  Here's what the MS Word first 2 chunks looks like in a couple of documents I just checked:

`D0 CF 11 E0 A1 B1 1A E1`

You could **MAKE A BACKUP** and try changing the first several bytes to that signature and see if it doesn't at least TRY to open as the right thing.

Generally, `file` can look at this area:
[image]
And tell the file-type.  If it's detecting it wrong, either it actually is a text file renamed to doc or the header got borked.

Answer (score 0):

1. In Nautilus, right-click on any file with the desired filetype or extension, choose `Properties` from the context menu.
2. In `Properties` click on the `Open With`.
3. Select an application for the given filetype (`writer` I asssume). All files with the same extension will now be opened with this program by default.

[image]

You can do this manually too

- `/usr/share/applications/defaults.list` holds the defaults (ie. system wide associations).
- `~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list` holds user specifics.

By the way: I assume you have software installed (ie. LibreOffice) that can open `doc` files?

---

From the comments and images added:

- it could be that the file is corrupt. What a file is is based on the 1st byte of a file (and not the extension as Windows does). What you could do is set `.txt` files to open with Writer (just temporary) and see if it then does open and then save it under another name. 
  Then reset opening `txt` to Gedit or what it was before.

Comment: Nope. Not that simple. - http://i.imgur.com/n7Fuy.png

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/M9X1K.jpg

Comment: hey, it takes time to take good lookin' screenshots! ;) only shows the rest of the libreoffice suite. - http://i.stack.imgur.com/CXMsd.png

Comment: Changing default application which is set to open a file by default, does not changes the file MIME type. In [my case](http://askubuntu.com/questions/586476/how-to-assign-set-a-mime-type-to-a-file) I selected "Font viewer" as default application, but MIME type was same as before: **ODF template (application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.formula-template)**

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The question is about changing MIME type, not change the application that opens a mime type