# Having problems with icons of new file i create

Tags: icons, 20.04

I have installed Cherry Tree, which I use to take my notes. Problem is that when I save my file, it has the usual plain `.txt` file icon.

I have tried creating a cherry tree file in `/home/Templates` directory and changed its icon with a `.png` image from web, but even this doesn't change the default behavior of cherry Tree files.

Can someone help in this regard, please.

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS in dual boot. I am one week on Linux.

Comment: If you're using 20.04, why did you tag 12.04?  Please clarify your release.

Answer (score 0):

The Cherry Tree note taking application can save in SQlite format (binary database format) or in XLM format (text format). For these file types, it uses the `.ctb` and `.ctd` extensions, respectively.

The issue is that the installation process of Cherry Tree does not create a mime type for these files. Accordingly, the extension is not registered, and Ubuntu looks at the nature of the file to determine the file type.

Proceed as following to make sure that a Cherry tree document is by default opened with Cherry tree when you double-click it:

1. Right-click the cherry tree document, and select "Properties".
2. On the "Open with" tab, select "Cherry Tree" and click "Set as default".
3. Close the dialog

This will allow you to open a Cherry Tree file by clicking. To make sure that a Cherry Tree document always has a specific icon would require to create a new mime type and set an icon. [While this can be done](https://askubuntu.com/questions/586476/how-to-assign-set-a-mime-type-to-a-file), it is a technical and complex procedure requiring work at the terminal.