# Set default office suite on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Tags: 22.04, libreoffice, default-programs, wps-office

I would prefer using WPS office for opening pre existing files as I find it has better compatibility with files created in microsoft office but prefer libreoffice for creating new files. If i have both installed any pre existing files will open in libreoffice. Is there a way to make .docx and .xlsx files open in WPS office and .odt files to open in lbreoffice?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to assign (set) a MIME type to a file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/586476/how-to-assign-set-a-mime-type-to-a-file)

Answer (score 0):

Right click on any .docx or .xlsx file, click on properties, and set to open it with WPS Office.

Right click on any .odt file, click on properties, and set to open it with LibreOffice.

Comment: Yes this does work I was more wondering if there was a way to set the default as after doing this the next time I open any file type it opens in libre office. Even opening everything in WPS office by default would be acceptable

Comment: @SirChipalot Once you set the default program for a file, all files of the same extension are opened by the same default program.

Comment: After opening the document in WPS office the default does not change and there is no button to set a new default

Comment: @SirChipalot Sorry I did not understand. Can  you edit the question and post a screenshot?